# search result related

Tags: search

I want to display up to  200 words of the related results just in the next line to title 
But i am not getting the text that {excerpt} should Display

My code is written below

```
{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}


<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" width="100%">

{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}

    <tr class="{switch}">
   {if page_meta_title != ""} <td width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{if page_meta_resource}{page_meta_resource}{if:elseif page_meta_override_url}{page_meta_override_url}{if:else}/{title_permalink}{/if}">{title}</a></b></td>{/if}    
</tr>
<tr><td style="color:red!important">{excerpt}</td></tr>
    {if count == total_results}
        </table>
    {/if}

    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}

{/exp:search:search_results}

</table>
```

Comment: In your code, you appear to have 2 opening {exp:search:search_results} tags. Is this indeed the case? If so, remove the top one.

Answer (score 2):

The `{excerpt}` variable, which is defined in [the Channel Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#which-field-should-be-used-for-search-excerpt), consists of the first 50 words from the field specified ([see docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html#excerpt)). If you need more than that, you're probably better off using the regular custom field notation and using something like [Hacksaw](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw) or [TruncHTML](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/trunchtml) to limit that field to 200 words.

To make sure the `{excerpt}` is defined correctly:

- Go to CP > Admin > Channel administration > Channels;
- Go to Edit Preferences for a channel;
- Under Administrative Preferences, make sure *Which field should be used for search excerpt?* points to the correct field (only fields that have been set as “searchable” will be included);
- Repeat for each relevant channel.

Comment: Low!! as you see in my code i have already used {excerpt}..But i am not getting the text

Comment: Make sure it's correctly defined in the Channel Preferences: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#which-field-should-be-used-for-search-excerpt

Comment: Can you give me some hint?

Comment: I thought I did with that link. Updated my answer with a step by step walkthrough.

Comment: I got an option called ***Which field should be used for search excerpt?*** Under 
**Administrative Preferences**
But i am just getting **Blog Body** in a drop down next to it

Comment: Quoting the docs: "*Only fields that have been set as “searchable” will be included.*"

Comment: I guess I am missing with something ..Because ai am just getting the title .. am not  getting {full_text} also..Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have writen all this code in a temple file.. and i am using it,, i didn't create any widget

Answer (score 0):

As Low has already said, you need to set the field as searchable.

To do that, go to the Channel Field that you want to use as the excerpt and set ***Is field searchable?*** to ***Yes***.

Then go back to the Channel preferences and you should now be able to select that field in the ***Which field should be used for search excerpt?*** dropdown.